# What does proportionate exactly mean here?

Tags: employment, terms-of-service, employer

In an offer letter offered to me by an organization it states that:

> If the trainee leaves the service of the corporation before expiry of
>   the bond period, he shall pay damages to the corporation proportionate
>   to the period of service yet to be rendered out of the total bond
>   period(4 Years) in terms of Remuneration OR rupee 4,00,000 ,whichever
>   is higher.

Say I leave after 2 years. **Does that mean I have to pay salary of remaining 2 years to the corporation? if it exceeds 4,00,000**

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say I leave after 2 years. Does that mean I have to pay salary of
>   remaining 2 years to the corporation? if it exceeds 4,00,000

Yes, that's what it means. At the outset, I'll point out that four years is too long for a traineeship (apropos of the clause's reference to you as "trainee"). Thus, in digressing from your precise inquiry, I strongly discourage you from consenting to that clause.

Since (1) you speak in terms of *salary*; (2) you use the SE tag *employment*; and (3) the so-called "bond period" is four years, the "corporation" evidently is abusing the notion of *traineeship* to tie your hands for that multi-year period (and, of course, with the low salary that is typical of a traineeship). Akin to my answer and comments in [this recent inquiry](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/30704/can-my-work-force-me-to-pay-for-their-compulsory-in-house-training), it seems that the "corporation" seeks to secure its supply of [underpaid] workforce.

**Edited on 8/6/2018 to remove last paragraph** (misreading of term "*service of the corporation*"). Per richardb's observation.

Comment: I presume English isn't your first language but the whole last paragraph is based on a misunderstanding of what the word 'service' means.

Comment: @richardb Thank you. You are right. I misread the term as *by* instead of *of*. The paragraph has been removed.